# looking for a way (with grease/tampermonkey) to replace part of url(s) on page

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey

So I frequent a webpage which uses ouo.io to try and make some advertisement money on links. Lucky me that that particular redirector-service doesnt alter or hide the original url in any way, so I was thinking that perhaps it would be possible (with a tamper/greasemonkey script I guess) to remove the ouo part from the urls automatically

The urls are like this
https:// ouo.io/qs/pRqHNWPK?s=https://destination.url/
(The space between the protocol and the ouo part was intentional because without it this link trips the URL-shortener warning thus not letting me post)

Anybody who has a tampermonkey script that would be adaptable for this situation? I tried messing around and writing something myself but that didn't work (or do anything at all lmao).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code to show you how it can be done ...
*(remove extra space added before ouo)*

Redirecting based on `location.href` of the new page

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Remove Redirect
// @match         https:// ouo.io/qs/*
// @grant         none
// @version       1.0
// run-at         document-start
// ==/UserScript==


const redirect = location.search.match(/http.+/);  // find redirect URL
if (redirect) {
  window.stop();                                   // stop loading the page
  location.href = decodeURIComponent(redirect[0]);
}
```

You can also change the links on the pages. It is much more resource intensive since it has to run on every page thus not recommended. Here is an example ...

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Remove Redirect Link
// @match         *://*/*
// @grant         none
// @version       1.0
// ==/UserScript==

document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="https:// ouo.io/qs/"]').forEach(item => {
  const redirect = item.search.match(/http.+/);   // find redirect URL
  if (redirect) {
   item.href = decodeURIComponent(redirect[0]);
  }
}):
```